# Convert Long URLs to Bit.ly URLs from Ruby on Rails database on show scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, url-shortener, bit.ly

I am REALLY new to RoR, but I have always figured the best way to learn a language is to jump in head first. I am working on creating a report generating webapp in RoR.
My progress thus far:

> rails new Project
>
> cd Project
>
> rails generate scaffold database League_Name:string Logo_URL:string Event_URL:string Website:string Facebook:string Twitter:string Youtube:string Funding:string Owner:string Phone:string Email:string Other:string Attendence:string Events_per_Year:string Locations:string Rules:string How_to_Enter:string Notable_Streamers:string Event_Titles:string Background:text game1_title:string game1_genre:string game1_website:string game1_years_played:string game1_prize_pool:string game1_prize_awarded:string game1_live:string game1_transmitted:string game1_method:string game1_advance_entry:string game1_invitational:string game1_contestants_open:string game1_contestants_finals:string game1_bracket_open:string game1_bracket_finals:string game1_rules:text game2_title:string game2_genre:string game2_website:string game2_years_played:string game2_prize_pool:string game2_prize_awarded:string game2_live:string game2_transmitted:string game2_method:string game2_advance_entry:string game2_invitational:string game2_contestants_open:string game2_contestants_finals:string game2_bracket_open:string game2_bracket_finals:string game2_rules:text game3_title:string game3_genre:string game3_website:string game3_years_played:string game3_prize_pool:string game3_prize_awarded:string game3_live:string game3_transmitted:string game3_method:string game3_advance_entry:string game3_invitational:string game3_contestants_open:string game3_contestants_finals:string game3_bracket_open:string game3_bracket_finals:string game3_rules:text game4_title:string game4_genre:string game4_website:string game4_years_played:string game4_prize_pool:string game4_prize_awarded:string game4_live:string game4_transmitted:string game4_method:string game4_advance_entry:string game4_invitational:string game4_contestants_open:string game4_contestants_finals:string game4_bracket_open:string game4_bracket_finals:string game4_rules:text
>
> rake db:migrate

I have preformed a little bit of CSS reformatting on the show scaffold, this part is coming along fine. In the long run, I would like to enter in all my data and when I click show have it return something like this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsOtsP63Kb2mdFpKZFZ6OV9PQmVWUU9Qc1FzV2UtVGc

All of this is fine; however, sometimes the URL for the website facebook twitter etc is longer then the < td> will allow with my formatting and the text just trails off. I have done some searching and I have found a few sites that say it is possible to create a shorter URL with the bitly service. These sites are pretty vague for the beginner.

http://coryschires.com/how-to-shorten-urls-with-bit-ly-in-ruby-on-rails/

Seems to be on the right track with what I want, however I don't know how to make

```
<tr>
<td class="td1">Website:</td>
<td><%= @database.Website %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="td1">Facebook:</td>
<td><%= @database.Facebook %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="td1">Twitter:</td>
<td><%= @database.Twitter %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="td1">Youtube:</td>
<td><%= @database.Youtube %></td>
</tr>
```

Yield a bit.ly version of the URL. And I dont understand how to implement his example into my work.